# Setup Git for Angular library with several projects

Tags: angular, git, github, angular-module, angular-library

I am working on an Angular library (its my first one and I did the setup like [this](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/the-best-way-to-architect-your-angular-libraries-87959301d3d3)). My folder structure looks like this:

- My-Library

  - Project1_API
  - dist
  - projects

    - project1
    - project2
    - my-ui-library
  - package.json

Now I need to init git and I would like to have project1, Project1_API and project2 in their own repository (only for versioning and private on Github). But the library setup and my-ui-library should be public and in a different repository. Another problem is that the package.json stores information for all 3 projects.

So whats the best way to do that in git? Or do I need to change my project setups?

I was checking git submodules and git subtree, but both seem to be very painful to maintain. Is it maybe a good way to put the private folders in the .gitignore and have the private folders as own repository?

Please help, I am a bit lost...

Answer (score 1):

In your workspace add the projects you don't want to be pushed to git with your main workspace to your .gitignore file.

```
# See http://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.

#ignored standalone projects
/projects/project1
/projects/project2
```

This will exclude your defined directories from being pushed to git.

Open a command prompt or terminal and cd into project1 for example.

```
cd /path/to/workspace/projects/project_name
```

Initialize a new git repo with:

```
git init
```

Do this for every project you want a seperate repository for. Now you can create your repo's on github.com and push to them.

Comment: Hey Jorn, yeah the "gitignore-way" might be the only way, if I want to keep the structure. I am also thinking about just pulling out the private projects again and use the library via npm. But thank you for the feedback :)